# Async method is promise but return undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, nuxt.js

I'm working on Nuxt.js app and try to use an `async` method to get data from api, but the result of the `async` method is always `undefined`. It looks like my methods aren't waiting for the response. I don't know what I've missed.
Here is my code in `methods: {..}`

```js
async getSomething() {
  console.log("getSomething");
  if (condition) {
    axios
      .get("api_url")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("getSomething success");
        return "success";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("getSomething fail 1");
        return "fail";
      });
  } else {
    console.log("getSomething fail 2");
    return "fail";
  }
}
doSomething() {
  console.log("do Something");
  this.getSomething().then((result) => {
    console.log("result", result);
    if (result === "success") {
      // do something on success
    } else {
      // do something on fail
    }
  });
  console.log("end doSomething");
}
```

I already try to logging `this.getSomething()` and the result is `Promise {<pending>}`
Here, when a method has been call on `created () {..}`

```
this.doSomething()
// doSomething
// getSomething
// end doSomething
// getSomething success
// result undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think part of your problem is that you're mixing async/await style of writing code with promise-chaining style. When you return 'fail' or 'success', you're usually returning from the `axios.get` callback, not from the `getSomething` method. You might want to rewrite your code a little like this:

```
async getSomething () {
    console.log('getSomething')
    if (condition) {
        try {
            let response = await axios.get('api_url')
            console.log('getSomething success')
            return 'success'
        } 
        catch(error) {
            console.log('getSomething fail 1')
            return 'fail'
        }
    } else {
        console.log('getSomething fail 2')
        return 'fail'
    }
}
```